# Automate website login without id/name

Tags: java, authentication, automation, htmlunit

I wanted to automate login to a website using java. I've researched a lot and am implementing it using HtmlUnit. However, the specific website I want to login to does not have values for id and name. Can someone please suggest what I can do here? All website's usually have a name or id when you inspect the login/password fields. This is how this particular website looks like.

```
<div class="js-one-auth">
<input type="email" class="js-email form-control input-lg"     placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="password" class="js-password form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter password">
<button type="submit" class="js-login btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 140px" disabled="">
<span class="vs-login-text">Log In</span>
<i class="vs-spinner fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></button>
<div class="js-caps-msg vs-login-msg alert alert-warning">Caps lock appears to be enabled</div>
</div>
```

Usually all the tutorials and suggestions i've found has a name or id field available between the input tags. I tried implementing this after referring to other sources, but the get element is only available for name/id.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("Site address");

HtmlElement usrname = page.getElementByName("email");
usrname.click();
usrname.type("myusername@123.com");

HtmlElement psswrd = page.getElementByName("password");
psswrd.click();
psswrd.type("mypassword");

HtmlElement signin = page.getElementByName("submit");
signin.click();
System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
webClient.close();;
```

}

Any suggestions how to get this done?

Comment: Have you tried to get the element by its attributes like `type`, `class`, or `placeholder`?

Comment: I tried doing something by extracting element by the xpath and also attribute. I got an empty list returned. So I dont know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

**take XPath for that input type**

1. email XPath-->//input[@type='email']
2. password Xpath-->//input[@type='password']

or

1. email Xpath-->//input[@class='js-email form-control input-lg']
2. password Xpath-->//input[@class='js-password form-control input-lg']